# Class inheritance, copy constructor and set/get functions

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, operators, copy-constructor

I got the following class:

```
class Matrix{
    private:
        int rows;
        int columns;
        double* matrix;
    public:
        Matrix();
        explicit Matrix(int N);
        Matrix(int M, int N);
        void setValue(int M, int N, double value);
        double getValue(int M, int N);
        bool isValid() const;
        int getRows();
        int getColumns();
        ~Matrix();
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, Matrix&matrix1);

        Matrix &operator=(const Matrix &m) {
            if (rows * columns != m.rows * m.columns){
                delete [] this->matrix;
                this->matrix = new double[m.rows * m.columns];
            }
            rows = m.rows;
            columns = m.columns;
            for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
                    this->matrix[i * columns + j] = m.matrix[i * columns + j];
                }
            }
            return *this;
        }
        Matrix(const Matrix &rhs);
};
```

with these functions

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Matrix.h"
using namespace std;

//OPPGAVE 2
Matrix::Matrix(){
    matrix = NULL;
}

Matrix::Matrix(int N){
    matrix = new double[N * N];
    rows = N;
    columns = N;

    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
            if(i==j)
                matrix[i * N + j] = 1;
            else
                matrix[i * N + j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

Matrix::Matrix(int M, int N){
    matrix = new double[M * N];
    rows = M;
    columns = N;

    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            matrix[i * N + j] =  0;
    }
}

Matrix::~Matrix(){
    delete [] matrix;
}

void Matrix::setValue(int M, int N, double value){
    matrix[M * columns + N] = value;
}

double Matrix::getValue(int M, int N){
    return matrix[M * columns + N];
}

bool Matrix::isValid() const{
    if(matrix==NULL)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

int Matrix::getRows(){
    return rows;
}

int Matrix::getColumns(){
    return columns;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream &out, Matrix&matrix1){
    if(matrix1.isValid())
        for(int i = 0; i < matrix1.getRows(); i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < matrix1.getColumns(); j++)
                out << matrix1.getValue(i,j) << "\t";
            out << endl;
        }
    else
        out << "Matrisen er ikke gyldig." << endl;
    return out;
}

Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix &rhs) : rows(rhs.rows), 
    columns(rhs.columns), 
    matrix(new double[rows * columns]) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                this->matrix[i * columns + j] = rhs.matrix[i * columns + j];
            }
        }
    }
```

The exercise says:

> a) Create a class Vector that inherits the MxN Matrix.
>   We want to use the Vector class as an interface to an Mx1 dimensional matrix with some
>   extra functionality.
>
> b) Implement the following constructors for the Vector class.
>
> • `Vector()`
>      Default constructor, should initialize the underlying matrix into the invalid state.
>
> • `explicit Vector(unsigned int N)`
>      Should construct the underlying Mx1 Matrix, initialized as a zero-matrix. (The  explicit keyword is not in the syllabus, but it should be used here.)
>
> • `Vector(const Matrix & other);`
>      Copy-constructor from Matrix. Should assign a matrix to *this if and only if the matrix has dimensions Nx1, otherwise the resulting *this should be set to invalid. Hint: Reuse operator= from the Matrix-class.

This is what I've got so far:

```
#include "Matrix.h"

class Vector : public Matrix{
    public:
        Vector();
        explicit Vector(int N);
        Vector(const Matrix & other);

};
```

and

```
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
#include "Vector.h"

Vector::Vector() 
    :Matrix(){ }

Vector::Vector(int N)
    :Matrix(N,1){ }
```

How am I supposed to reuse the operator= from Matrix? If I try to copy it from the Matrix class into the Vector class, it says that rows, columns etc is inaccessible. How do I access these?

Is it possible to write a copy constructor for the Vector class more or less the same as the copy constructor for the Matrix class? They are both arrays, so I guess it should work?

Will the operators I overloaded for Matrix (not included here) automaticly be used if I multiply a Matrix with a Vector, or do I also need to include these somehow in the Vector class? (They were written outside the Matrix class in the Matrix.cpp-file.)

Next Im going to write set and get functions for the Vector class.
Is it possible to write these functions on this form?:

```
void Vector::setValue(int i, double value) {
    Matrix::setValue(i, 1, value);
}
```

Help and tips are greatly appreciated!

Comment: If this is an excercise given to you by your professor you should tell him to learn proper C++, with kind regards from the Internet. This is a  horrible excercise.

Comment: How come? And yes, this is an offical exercise given at an university.

Comment: first, copy constructors are only to copy another instance of the same class, anything is not a copy ctor.  Secondly, what the heck is initializing a class to an invalid state anyways? What's the point of creating a vector class that does what Matrix already does?

Comment: I see what you mean, but I still need to do this though :P

Comment: That's just the beginning of the problems in `Matrix`, but in my experience, few professors appreciate criticism from their students; let's just get this junkheap in the air. Can you tell us what "*this should be set to invalid*" means? I've been programming in C++ for a *long* time and I've never heard of it.

Comment: "this should be set to invalid" probably means that isValid() returns false.

Comment: @rschuler: I missed that. And I've got to stop slapping my forehead every time I see something like it.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

What follows is hideous kludgery to satisfy an incompetent professor. *Don't do this in the real world.*

First, the misnamed "copy" constructor. If we weren't worried about the dimensions, we could do this (shudder):

```
Vector(const Matrix & other)
{
  *this = other;
}
```

But we must check the dimensions first. We could do it this way:

```
Vector(const Matrix & other)
{
  if(other.getColumns()==1)
      *this = other;
}
```

But some chucklehead neglected to make `getColumns()` const, so this results in a compiler error. We could do something truly drastic, *const cast*:

```
Vector(const Matrix & other)
{
  Matrix *p = const_cast<Matrix *>(&other);
  if(p->getColumns()==1)
      *this = other;
}
```

Or just something facepalmingly awful:

```
Vector(const Matrix & other)
{
  Matrix M(other); // notice that this is not const
  if(M.getColumns()==1)
      *this = other;
}
```

Do you need help with the `isValid` stuff?

Comment: Thanks, Ill give this a go. But where does it say that getColumns() is const? Also, how exactly do I reuse the operator= from the Matrix class?

Comment: @Ole1991: It *should* say in `Matrix.h` that `getColumns()` is const, but it doesn't. And this code uses the `operator=` thus: `*this = other;`. Now that I look at it, the `isValid` stuff isn't trivial. Are you sure you can't modify the `Matrix` class?

Comment: I got my copy constructor, operator= and set/get functions to work now. Thanks! I think I can manage the rest of the exercise on my own now :)

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track for the sets and gets.  You can call operators with member function like syntax  `Class::operator*(args)`.  Implementing the vector assignment would look something like this:

```
Vector & Vector::operator=(const Vector &v){
    Matrix::operator=(v);
    return *this;
}
```

You will want your Vector constructors to be declared public.  I am thinking because you are using inheritance the compiler will generate correct copy constructors and assignment operators for the Vector class.  You should write tests to verify this assumption.

Comment: "You will want your Vector constructors to be declared public." Just noticed this now. I meant to set them public, ofcourse :)